# What's the optimal distance from a pressure tank to the supply line connection?

Tags: plumbing

Is there an optimal distance from the pressure tank to install the Tee joining the line from the pump, line to the house and line to the pressure tank? We have a convertible jet pump with an injector bringing water from an 82 ft well. The line from the well comes up into the basement, the pump and pressure tank are within 8 feet of the well line. Currently the line comes out of the pump about 16" to a Tee with about a 24" line going to the pressure tank. All of this is at floor level with the house supply line running up the wall to the ceiling directly above. [image]

Comment: Make the pipe long enough for easy access for repairs/maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

The *optimal* distance is as close to the house feed line as possible. But *"less than optimal"* may not be enough difference to notice, particularly if the tank tee line is adequately large diameter. Are you experiencing a problem related to the pressure tank?

I'd personally be penciling in "replace with a submersible pump" for future water system considerations. Jet pumps are a technology whose time has come and gone, IMHO. They waste a lot of power, for one thing.

Comment: Thanks. Just replaced the pump & pressure tank so hope we've got a while before we need to do that again. The new pressure tank is providing adequate pressure. We were in a rush so just put the new pump & tank into the existing hose & clamp plumbing last weekend but want to replumb it from the pump to the house water line.

Comment: Another question. We plan to plumb with 3/4" PEX. Can we use PEX from the Tee to the pressure tank?

Comment: A "standard" tank tee is usually at least 1" pipe, so using 3/4" for that is not great, IMHO. The idea is to minimize flow-related pressure drop (aka dynamic head) into and out of the tank. Such "standard" tank tees are easily available, typically with a union to make tank replacement easier. *Unfortunate (unless there's some major issue getting power to the well) about the new jet pump.*

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth I have a 450ft deep well so if it really mattered then I should be having problems and I’m not.  Initially my pressure tank was at the entry point but when I finished my basement I relocated the tank to near the water heater on the other side of the basement which added 75 feet or so (being generous here) and it made ZERO difference.  I didn’t even have to adjust my tank.  Let me add that the distance will have no bearing on the pump life.  Taking the overall quality of your pump out of the equation (you get what you pay for.). Pump life is generally dictated by two things being the quality of your source water and how often it runs.  If you have a tiny pressure tank your pump will run far more to maintain pressure.  If your water is hard or high in iron your pump will fail due to mineral or metal deposits clogging the intake.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

The most important thing is to start at water pressure tank with 1 inch copper reduce to 3/4 then to 1/2 inch then to fixture of any thing and u will have optimal equal pressure at all units cause u did the proper volume displacement by graduating your plumbing from a greater pipe to a lesser pipe and u will never go wrong!Pax pipe or copper don't make a difference just go from greater pipe to lesser pipe!

Comment: Would you please [edit] your post to include some punctuation, that will make it much easier to read. Also, "you" is perfectly acceptable, and the savings of not transmitting the 2 extra characters are really pretty small. Additionally, is "Pax pipe" supposed to be "PEX pipe"? If not, you may want to specify what "Pax pipe" is as not everyone is familiar with that.